# Navigation problems with MVVMLight

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I'm having a couple of issues when trying to navigate using MVVMLight.

On iOS, I have created my NavigationService in AppDelegate/FinishedLoading with the following code

```
        var nav = new NavigationService();

        nav.Configure(ViewModelLocator.MainPageKey, "MainPage");
        nav.Configure(ViewModelLocator.MapPageKey, "MapPage");

        // iOS uses the UINavigtionController to move between pages, so will we
        nav.Initialize(Window.RootViewController as UINavigationController);

        // finally register the service with SimpleIoc
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => nav);
```

When I use NavigateTo to move between the two pages, I continually get the same error asking if I have called NavigationService.Initialize. Obviously I have. The first ViewController shows without a problem.

On Android, I'm having issues again with the second Activity, but with a different error.

I am passing a List< double> as the object parameter in NavigateTo and then in the Activity, use the following to retrieve the passed object

```
    void GetDataFromViewModel()
    {
        var NavService = (NavigationService)SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
        var data = NavService.GetAndRemoveParameter<object>(Intent) as List<double>;
        if (data != null)
        {
            ViewModel.Latitude = data[0];
            ViewModel.Longitude = data[1];
        }
    }
```

Problem is that straight after the base.OnCreate in my OnCreate method, the app crashes out with the error

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Type not found in cache: System.Object.
```

My NavigateTo line looks like this

```
INavigationService navigationService;
...code
navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.MapPageKey, new List<double> { Latitude, Longitude });
```

This has got me stumped!